# My suffix is the suffix of the superfix of a holy man

Tags: riddle, word

> My prefix is not real.
>   My infix makes you more judicious.
>   My suffix is the suffix of the superfix of a holy man.
>   Despite these divisions, my whole is indivisible.

What am I?

Hint:

> Take a more literal understanding of the word "superfix" than its traditional definition.

Hint:

> -fix: (affix) an additional element placed at the beginning or end of a root, stem, or word, or in the body of a word, to modify its meaning.
>  super- : above.
>  My infix is an initialism, not properly a word.
>  My prefix is a word, not the imaginary constant.

Hint:

> My prefix brings communication to life
>  My infix brings more learning to those at the bar
>  My suffix is an anagram for a burn, as the natural greenery gives way to black

Comment: Can I ask what the definition of 'superfix' is in this puzzle?  As far as I can tell, it has to do with pronunciation, and not a subset of letters.  Is this correct?

Comment: You might have to add further clues to constrain your answer otherwise you would end up with plausibly many solutions.

Comment: just a thought to spur more ideas - since the op mention a literal interpretation of superfix, perhaps the superfix of a holy man is actually just meaning one of the hats that some of them wear. The suffix of that. I was going to attempt narrowing it down and making my own guess, but I'm not a religious person myself and familiar with that field. On a quick search, there are TONS of different types of headwear for different holymen.. so `-\_,('-'),_/-`

Comment: @Sensoray Or, perhaps, [a hat-sounding title](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahatma_Gandhi)? (j/k...  I think)

Answer (score 12):

It's a bit rough, but here's a starting guess:

> Are you **Irrational**?

"My prefix is not real"...

> So it is *imaginary*: i

"My infix makes you more judicious"...

> (R)ration(s): allow more judicious allocation/use of resources.

"My suffix is the suffix of the superfix of a holy man"...

> Al: The final part of *[cardinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_(Catholic_Church))*, as in the religious position in the Catholic church. The word is used as a title, which is not a superfix so this is a bit of a stretch.

"Despite these divisions, my whole is indivisible"...

> Irrational numbers are indivisible in the sense that they cannot be expressed as a ratio of two integers.

Comment: don't know the answer but you have awesome explained your answer :)

Comment: You get an upvote for a well thought answer, but this is incorrect.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov, many of the answers in here fit pretty well to your riddle. If they are incorrect, you may provide reasons to refute them or add a clarification in the question.

Answer (score 9):

My prefix is not real.

> $i$ - an imaginary unit.

My infix makes you more judicious.

> i/I - abbreviation for information or intelligence, as in IT or IQ, can help in making decisions.

My suffix is the suffix of the superfix of a holy man.

> i - suffix of the titles Rabb**i** and Swam**i**.

Despite these divisions, my whole is indivisible.

> i/I - one in Roman numerals, can't be divided into smaller whole numbers, and is a one-letter word.

Answer (score 5):

I had this silly idea, that completely depends on OP having played fast and loose with the various -fixes. Given the somewhat frivolous fixations in the title, I'm willing to give that theory a chance:

Are you, perhaps,

> an **int**?

My prefix is not real.

> the `int` data type can store only integers, not real numbers

My infix makes you more judicious.

> The **INT** stat (short for intelligence) will give you better judgement in many role-playing games.

My suffix is the suffix of the superfix of a holy man.

> If you superfix a holy man, you get sa'int (stress on the newly created second syllable), whose suffix is "int"

Despite these divisions, my whole is indivisible.

> The whole ("int") is too short to be sensibly split into pieces, which explains the various "-fixes" actually being the whole word.

Yes, I do realise I may be *wildly*  off the mark with all this :)

Answer (score 4):

It might be

> **ivisible**

Because

> i - not real prefix
>  visi - Latin for to visit/go see/look at, the empiric action that makes  you more judicious
>  ble - suffix of bible, the holy man is attached / (super)fixed to it
>
>  ... and its whole is in-"divisible"

Answer (score 4):

I think you might be:

> [**CONURBAN**](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/conurban) (i.e. describing a *conurbation* - a settlement made up of smaller settlements that almost seemlessly merge into one another, e.g. Greater London in the UK).

*My prefix is not real.*

> It's all a **CON**!

*My infix makes you more judicious.*

> National University (**NU**) in California offers [online courses](https://www.collegechoice.net/rankings/cheapest-online-law-schools/) in Law, helping to make you '*more judicious*'. Alternatively, this might be a reference to the former [National University School of Law](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_University_School_of_Law).

*My suffix is the suffix of the superfix of a holy man.*

> If we interpret 'superfix' as meaning 'something that goes on *top*' and 'suffix' as the usual 'take the last letters of...' then this can yield **URBAN**, since a *turban* is a head covering (i.e. 'superfix') traditionally worn by those who practise Sikhism. (I had previously been so positive this was referring to a 'halo' that I must express thanks to @Sensoray for suggesting in comments the idea of a religious hat instead...).

*Despite these divisions, my whole is indivisible.*

> A settlement that is **CONURBAN** comprises smaller settlements that have grown to fill their surrounding areas so that there is no longer space between them. They have become one great, *indivisible* mass of sprawling streets!

Regarding the last hint:

> *My prefix brings communication to life*
>  *My infix brings more learning to those at the bar*
>  *My suffix is an anagram for a burn, as the natural greenery gives way to black*
>
>  **CON** is also short for 'convention' (e.g. [comic con](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comic_book_convention), where the world of comics and other forms of entertainment are 'brought to life' through 'cosplay', autograph/selfie-hunting and special events). **NU** as outlined above satisfies this rewording too (since 'at the bar' is a phrase meaning 'practising Law'). Meanwhile, **URBAN** is an anagram of '*a burn*', and the *natural greenery* of the countryside meets the *black* of city buildings at the edge of a conurbation, where the houses begin.

Answer (score 2):

You could be

> **ENTWINE**

My prefix is not real.

> **ENT** - tree men from LOTR, fiction based.

My infix makes you more judicious.

> **WIN** - a win makes one think that they can judge others because they have earned experience

My suffix is the suffix of the superfix of a holy man.

> **E** - Jesus, the Holiest to Christians.  Je being the superfix. The suffix of that being E.

Despite these divisions, my whole is indivisible.

> **ENTWINE** - if divided, something that is entwined will be no longer.

Thoughts

> **WINE** could maybe make someone more judgy,  but then no suffix would be needed. So, **WIN** it is. Still feels like I'm reaching though.

Answer (score 2):

My guessing it’s an

> **imager**

*My prefix is not real.*

> $i$ for imaginary number; it’s opposite to real number

*My infix makes you more judicious.*

> **age** could make one more judicious

*My suffix is the suffix of the superfix of a holy man.*

> **er** is the suffix of the superfix of [*fakeer*](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/fakeer) (stressed in the second syllable)

*Despite these divisions, my whole is indivisible.*

> An **imager** is something that makes or records images. It cannot do its function should it be be divided.

Comment: doesn't your explainations leave the second letter in your word unaccounted for?

Comment: @SteveV The OP did not state that the affixes encompass the word in its entirety. So I found my guess acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

Another answer (actually the same as @Bass 's, but with different explanations):

> Are you an `int` data type?

My prefix is not real.

> The prefix is $i$, an imaginary unit. It is not real.

My infix makes you more judicious.

> Infix is $n$, a common designation for sample size in statistics. Having a larger sample usually allows you to make more judicious decisions about the properties of that sample.

My suffix is the suffix of the superfix of a holy man.

> Suffix is $t$, last letter of "Saint" (a common title of a "holy man").

Despite these divisions, my whole is indivisible.

> Integers (or *whole* numbers) are "indivisible" in the sense that the set of integers is not closed under division operation (i.e. you cannot always divide an integer by an integer to produce another integer).

Answer (score 2):

Might be:

> **Imperil**

My prefix is not real.

> Prefix is $i$, the imaginary number

My infix makes you more judicious.

> Infix is $mper$, which constitutes the word $perm$, which curls your hair and makes you look like a judge (at least in the saxon world), thus more judicious

My suffix is the suffix of the superfix of a holy man.

> Suffix is $il$, from the superfix (on a cross) $nail$ of a holy man (christ)

Despite these divisions, my whole is indivisible.

> The whole is indivisible since imperil is an untangible concept.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely a particularly serious answer, but I can just about make it fit the clues.  Are you...

> Superman!

> My prefix is not real.
>
> > Real things are common nouns.  "Super" is an adjective, so it is not a real thing.

> My infix makes you more judicious.
>
> > A "perm" (hairstyle) somewhat resembles [a judge's wig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Court_dress).  Thus, making you more "judicious".

> My suffix is the suffix of the superfix of a holy man.
>
> > A "superfix" is something above which gives meaning.  That which is above, and gives meaning to, a holy man (or woman) is a god (or goddess).  A suffix, meaning "God", commonly found in Hebrew-root names is "-el" (Micha**el**, "Who is like God?" / Gabri**el**, "God is my Strength" /  Ang**el**, "Messenger of God")
> >
> >  Superman's birth name is "Kal **El**", with his surname being a bit on the end that adds additional meaning - i.e. a *suffix*.

> Despite these divisions, my whole is indivisible.
>
> > Superman is well known for his nigh-invincible nature, making him indivisible.
> >  Also, unlike Marvel heroes, such as [Spider-Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man) (respect the hyphen!) or [Wonder Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wonder_Man), DC heroes tend to have "man" as a suffix instead of as a separate word (Superman, Batman, Aquaman…)